# Pass data attribute to vue 3 root instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking to pass data to a vue 3 root instance. For context I am running various stand alone vue apps on a webpage and these are generated as there own instances.

When I set up the HTML like so

```
<div id="app" data-user="user"></div>
```

Where `data-user` contains an object is there a way to grab this when initialising the application like so

```
createApp(RecommendedJobsWidget).mount("#recommendedJobsWidgetInstance");
```

I essentially want to pass `data-user` into `RecommendedJobsWidget`

Vue 2 had `propsData` but it has now changed and I can't seem to find any relevant information from the documentation on `createApp` here https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html

Comment: FYI, HTML attributes can only be strings. Are you actually passing a stringified object? Or are you binding an object?